# Como puedo solo seleccionar ciertos campos de un array en otro

Tags: array

Buen dia, tengo un array que se genera desde una consulta JSON, que muestra codigo, descripcion y precio1, precio2,preci3,precio4,precio y precio6.
El detalle es que de este array quiero crear un OPTION (lista de precio).
El array que se genera es el siguiente:

```
Array(
    [codigo] => xxx-1                
    [descrip] => descirpcion del producto
    [bodega01] => 2270.00
    [precio1a] => 15.90
    [precio1] => 15.14
    [precio2] => 14.46
    [precio3] => 13.82
    [precio4] => 13.25
    [precio5] => 12.72
)
```

de este array solo quiere los precios para formar mi OPTION (lista de precios)
pero al generarla me dice que los valores son UNDEFINED

[image: Este es el codigo que uso para crear la liste de precios]

Answer (score 0):

Podrías llamar la propiedad entre corchetes

```
var listaprecio = [
     precio1A : {"precio":info['precio1a']}
];
```

Comment: Gracias, Martin ya realicé los cambios que me sugeriste, pero siempre me sale como UNDEFINED